# About constructor with parameters

Tags: java

I have a question about constructors, if I make a contructor like:
 **Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);**
if I have understood it correctly the originOne will be pointing to 23 and 94.
When i try to print it with System.out.println(originOne) i dont get these values, how come?

Thanks in advance!  =)

Comment: thats not a constructor

Comment: This is the output of your program : java.awt.Point[x=23,y=94]

Comment: Do you use the awt.Point or a do you wrote your own class ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can override the toString() function of your class Point to make it print just like you want it to. Example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return this.X + "IEATBABYCLOWNS" + this.Y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Point` is not `java.awt.Point`.

You need to override `toString()` of `Point` class, since one of the overloaded methods of `PrintStream#println()` (System.out is a `PrintStream`) takes an object as a parameter, uses the object's `toString()` to get a string representation of the object, and then prints it:

[java.io.PrintStream#println(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
public void println(Object x) {
     String s = String.valueOf(x);
     synchronized (this) {
         print(s);
         newLine();
     }
}
```

[java.lang.String#valueOf(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

---

Overriding the class is as simple as adding the method and its implementation within it:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "x = " + x + " - y = " + y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println(originOne);
```

This calls the toString method of the class of that object. And since you didnt override it, it calls the toString of the Object class.

Answer (score 0):

API description of java.awt.Point.toString():

```
Returns a string representation of this point and its location in the (x,y) 
coordinate space. This method is intended to be used only for debugging 
purposes, and the content and format of the returned string may vary between 
implementations. The returned string may be empty but may not be null.
```

As you can see, the output depends on which JVM you use, and you are not guaranteed to get what you want.

I would change the println to something like:

```
System.out.println("[" + originOne.getX() + ", " + originOne.getY() + "]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Override `toString` method. See below for your case

```
        package test;

        public class Point {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Point point = new Point(23, 94);

    System.out.println(point);
    }

    @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "x : " + x + " y: "+ y;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(originOne.getX() + " " + originOne.getY());
```